# Format ps STIME on Linux

Tags: linux, ps

I recently moved to Linux from HP-UX and I noticed that STIME of a process is in "MonthDate" format(e.g. Apr21) while on HP-UX it was "Month Date"(e.g. Apr 21). There is no space between month and date. Is there a way to get a space between month and date?

**HP-UX:**

```
root 16773     1  1  Jul 15  ?        67:23 /opt/ssh/sbin/sshd
```

**Linux:**

```
oper     24494 23075  0 Apr21 ?        00:00:00 sshd: oper@pts/8
```

Answer (score 0):

So once again I am digging procps-ng sources for the same [function pr_stime()](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/master/ps/output.c#L1017) sources. You may be interested in the command above that function.

No, you can't parse stime consistently. The format is not specified in the standard. The output from procps-ng/ps varies depending how long ago the process was created. Procps-ng/ps uses 3 format strings depending on how long time ago the process has started. If your script depends on it, you may be surprised they all will stop working on new years eve when ps starts using `%Y` format string for stime column.

For determining how long time ago a process was started on linux, use `etimes` or `etime` with procps-ng/`ps`.